# Symbol for double cross X?

Tags: symbols

does anyone know what's the LaTeX symbol for the double X, used in a stats book to denote the range?

[image: Symbol]

Comment: Hi and welcome, closest Detexify gives me right now is `\usepackage{ dsfont }` with `\mathds{X}`. But you could always use `kern` to moveone X back.

Comment: If have never seen this symbol before

Comment: this symbol is not in unicode.  if it appears in a published document, please post a reference.  i will be happy to submit it for consideration to the unicode technical committee.

Comment: @JamesMcmillan  This symbol is probably unique to that textbook. I am curious as to which Statistics Book this symbol is used for range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The symbol can be constructed from the sans serif math font, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\RangeX}{%
  \mathsf{X}\mkern-9mu\mathsf{X}%
}

\begin{document}
  , the \textbf{range} of $X$, denoted $\RangeX$,  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the symbol is also used in the smaller math styles (`\scriptstyle`, `\scriptscriptstyle`), then the width approximation by the `\mkern` command does not work too well. The following more complicate definition measures the width of the symbol to get a better spacing between the symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\RangeX}{%
  {%
    \mathpalette\@RangeOf{X}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@RangeOf}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: symbol, which is duplicated
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\mathsf{#2}$}%
  \mathsf{#2}%
  \kern-\wd0 %
  \mkern2.75mu\relax
  \nonscript\mkern.25mu\relax
  \mathsf{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[ \RangeX \scriptstyle \RangeX \scriptscriptstyle \RangeX \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for refined symbol]

Comment: To make it perfect, you should hide the `textbf` in some semantic macro as well ;-) Nevertheless, +1

Comment: @Johannes_B The semantic macro `\emph` is provided in egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237783/16967). He also uses `\mathop` for the symbol, also a good idea.

Comment: I was talking of `textbf` which is now gone anyway. Great answer. I would upvote again, if i could :-)

Answer (score 13):

It's easy to use a zero space sans serif X, then a small space and then another sans serif X:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\range}{%
  \mathop{\mathrlap{\mathsf{X}}\mspace{3mu}\mathsf{X}}%
}

\begin{document}

The \emph{range} of $X$, denoted $\range$.

The range of $f$ is $\range f$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same if I add `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}`:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\newcommand{\statrange}{{\sffamily X\kern-.5em X}}
\begin{document}
the range of X, denoted \statrange,
\end{document}
```

[image: jamesmcmillanStatRange]

Comment: Of course, this answer lacks the math support the other answers (so far) provide.