# Combine two symbols to one fully scalable

Tags: stacking-symbols, stackengine

I have to put a colon inside a `bigcup` symbol, so that the result is treated exactly like the latter.

I tried different approaches following various posts here and on other places. The best result until now is taking advantage of the package `stackengine`.

If I use the `cup` it works correctly, it really looks the same.

If I use the `bigcup`, on the other hand, the result is not correctly scaled, as you can see with the following code and the attached picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\bigcupcolon}{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{}{c}{+.25ex}{:}{\bigcup}}}}
\newcommand{\cupcolon}{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{-.18ex}{c}{+0.1ex}{:}{\cup}}}}

\begin{document}
    $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}    $S_1\cup S_2$
    \vspace{20pt}

    $\displaystyle\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}    $S_1\cupcolon S_2$

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of wrong scaling]

So the question is, how would you write such a symbol?

Comment: Have a look at Heikos great answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237780/symbol-for-double-cross-x/237781#237781

Comment: off topic: what is the meaning of that union?

Comment: @sigur I use it to glue together things with two distinct special points and identifying this special points. It is similar to the coproduct of pointed sets, but with one more special point.

Comment: @dadexix86, thanks. In the case for two, is it a kind of quotient of the wedge `$S_1\vee S_2$`!

Comment: @sigur Yes, set-wise it looks exactly as doing it two times, but I am working with pointed monoid, so the two elements (the special point and the identity) behave rather differently.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `stackengine` does not explicitly preserve the math style (i.e., `\textstyle` or `\displaystyle`).  Thus, while one could hardwire that or do a `\mathchoice`, here, I use the `scalerel` packages `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` feature to save the math style and import it into the `\stackinset`.

In the MWE, I show `\bigcupcolon` in both math styles.

EDITED to make smaller dots in the regular cup, and EXTENDED to handle all math styles, including `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. (Note, though, that `\bigcup` does not appear to have a `\scriptscriptstyle` version.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\bigcupcolon}{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{-1.4pt}{c}{+.25\LMex}{:}{\SavedStyle\bigcup}}}}}
\newcommand{\cupcolon}{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.3\LMpt}{c}{-1\LMpt}{\SavedStyle^:}{\SavedStyle\cup}}}}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}    
$\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$S_1\cup S_2$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\displaystyle\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$S_1\cupcolon S_2$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\scriptstyle\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$\scriptscriptstyle\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}S_i$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\scriptstyle S_1\cupcolon S_2$\hspace{40pt}
$\scriptscriptstyle S_1\cupcolon S_2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the same-sized colons don't really look so good.  in particular, the colon in the regular-sized `\cup` looks oversized.  i'd try both a regular and a bold colon in a smaller size (bold so that the "thickness" of the dots is in keeping with the thickness of the stroke forming the cup), then decide which looks better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'll have a look at that after lunch.

Comment: This looks already amazing but yes, scaling the dot inside would be absolutely perfect! :D

Comment: @dadexix86 Please see revision.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Employed a scripted colon in the regular-sized cup, and extended the solution for all math styles.

Comment: all look a lot better except for the very last.  well, that's the smallest colon available without applying a `\scalebox`.  too bad.

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52673/4427

In the “binary” version, the colon is built by hand with small periods, because the ordinary colon would be too big in comparison with the cup symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\moverlay{\mathpalette\mov@rlay}
\def\mov@rlay#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{%
   \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
   \ialign{\hfil$\m@th#1##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}
\newcommand{\charfusion}[3][\mathord]{%
    #1{\ifx#1\mathop\vphantom{#2}\fi
        \mathpalette\mov@rlay{#2\cr#3}%
      }%
    \ifx#1\mathop\expandafter\displaylimits\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ccolon}{\mathpalette\doccolon\relax}
\newcommand{\doccolon}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox8{$#1\mkern3.5mu$}%
    \smash{$\scriptscriptstyle.$}%
    \vskip\wd8
    \smash{$\scriptscriptstyle.$}%
    \vskip\ifdim\wd8<.15\normalbaselineskip.5\else.2\fi\wd8
  }%
}

\newcommand{\cupcolon}{\charfusion[\mathbin]{\cup}{\ccolon}}
\newcommand{\bigcupcolon}{\charfusion[\mathop]{\bigcup}{:}}

\begin{document}

\[
\mbox{inline: }{\textstyle A_{X\cupcolon Y} \cupcolon B_{\bigcupcolon B_{j}}}
\qquad
\mbox{display: }
\bigcupcolon_{i\in I} A_{i}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This look wonderful! :D Just one question, why would you use `\mathbin` and not `\mathop` in the inline version?

Comment: @dadexix86 I use `\mathbin` for the binary operation version. If you do `$\bigcupcolon_{i\in I}A_i}$` you'll get the operator form (smaller than in display style). Just the same relationship as between `\cup` and `\bigcup`.

Comment: I thought that also `\cup` was considered an operator. I read some documentation now and understand your code better. Thanks! :D

Comment: @dadexix86 It's common to find `\cup_{i=1}^{n}`, but it's wrong nonetheless.