# Union with text inside

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I would like to create math symbol similar to set Union (big U) where I can insert inside an arbitrary word or symbol (e.g. "foo"). Something along the lines of this solution: [Is a cupdot symbol available in amsmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/is-a-cupdot-symbol-available-in-amsmath) but with any text instead of dot. Is it possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Simply replacing the `\cdot` with `\text{foo}` should work. Not sure how good it will look like though as there is not much space in there.

Comment: See e.g.  `\stackinset` from the `stackengine` package – and probably use it with `\bigcup`.

Comment: How many letters might be in the word that should be placed inside the cup (union) symbol?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243478/combine-two-symbols-to-one-fully-scalable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\uwithtext}[1]{\DOTSB\mathbin{\text{\tikz{%
    \node (a) {#1};
    \draw[black, rounded corners=1.2ex] 
        ([yshift=-2pt]a.north west) -- (a.south west) -- (a.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]a.north east);}}}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    A \uwithtext{a} B \quad 
    X_{A \uwithtext{a} B} \quad 
    A \uwithtext{ab} B \quad 
    X_{A \uwithtext{ab} B} \quad 
    A \uwithtext{abp} B \quad 
    X_{A \uwithtext{abp} B}  
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To enhance compatibility with the `amsmath` package, you might want to add `\DOTSB` at the beginning of `\uwithtext`.

Comment: @GuM Added, thank you! Did I add it in the correct place?

Comment: Yes, it’s in the correct place.  You might want to have a look at how, say, the `\skull` command is implemented in the `halloweenmath` package (search the code for `\newcommand*\skull`.

Comment: @krokodil You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer and please don't eat ducks! :):):):)