# How to typeset "\utimes" (akin to \uplus)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the easiest way to typeset - in math mode - a symbol similar to `\uplus` (the symbol for disjoint set union, consisting of a plus embedded inside a union symbol), only with a "times" symbol substituting for the plus?

Comment: Some fonts provide `\utimes`, but that does not look like you want to have it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Which fonts? If it already exists, I'd like to use it.

Comment: @Mico: `mathdesign` gives me an `Undefined control sequence` error message. As for the other two packages you mentioned - no, this is not the symbol I'm looking for.

Comment: @EvanAad: That's what I said before -- they look different

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I don't understand why, but I did as you requested.

Comment: If a dot instead of a times is acceptable, ⊍ (multiset multiplication) is U+228D. You can use it directly with `unicode-math`, which also defines it as `\cupdot`.

Comment: @EvanAad: As you see, my answer has no chance compared to other answers ;-)

Comment: what's the meaning of this symbol?  should it be added to unicode?  if so, a (published) example in context will be needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't know if there's a published example. I employ it for my personal use in the following sense. Given two families of sets, S and T, the expression S \utimes T denotes the family of sets consisting of all the sets of the form s union t, where (s,t) is a member of the cartesian product of S and T.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\uplus` appears to have status `mathbin`, whereas `\biguplus` appears to have status `mathop`. The following definitions of `\utimes` and `\bigutimes` preserve these settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for "\boldsymbol" macro

\newcommand\utimes{\mathbin{\ooalign{$\cup$\cr%
   \hfil\raise0.42ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\times$}\hfil\cr}}}
\newcommand\bigutimes{\mathop{\ooalign{$\bigcup$\cr%
   \hfil\raise0.36ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\boldsymbol{\times}$}\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}
$a\uplus a$  $a\biguplus a$

$a\utimes a$ $a\bigutimes a$

$\uplus\utimes$

${\biguplus}{\bigutimes}$
\end{document}
```

The arguments of `\raise` -- 0.42ex and 0.36ex, resp. -- were chosen to make `\uplus` and `\utimes` as similar in layout as possible, for the Computer Modern math font family -- which is the default font family in most TeX distributions (including the screenshot shown above). For other math font families, other arguments of `\raise` will probably have to be considered.

Answer (score 8):

Fitting `\times` into `\cup` is a pain; here I use `picture` mode for adding the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\utimes}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\u@times\relax}}
\newcommand\u@times[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\@tempswatrue\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\@tempswatrue\else
      \@tempswafalse
  \fi\fi
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1{\cup}$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \roundcap
  \linethickness{\variable@rule{#1}}
  \put(0,0){\box\z@}
  \if@tempswa
    \Line(0.3,0.25)(0.7,0.65)
    \Line(0.7,0.25)(0.3,0.65)
  \else
    \Line(0.3,0.2)(0.7,0.6)
    \Line(0.3,0.6)(0.7,0.2)
  \fi
  \end{picture}%
  \phantom{\cup}%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigutimes}{\DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\bigu@times\relax}\slimits@}
\newcommand{\bigu@times}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1{\bigcup}$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \roundcap
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \linethickness{2\variable@rule{#1}}
  \else
    \linethickness{1.5\variable@rule{#1}}
  \fi
  \put(0,0){\box\z@}
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \Line(0.25,0.0)(0.75,0.5)
    \Line(0.25,0.5)(0.75,0.0)
  \else
    \Line(0.3,0.1)(0.7,0.5)
    \Line(0.3,0.5)(0.7,0.1)
  \fi
  \end{picture}%
  \phantom{\bigcup}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\variable@rule}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8  
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont3\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont3\else
        \scriptscriptfont3\relax
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\uplus b\utimes c_{\uplus\utimes}$

$\displaystyle\biguplus\bigutimes
 \textstyle\biguplus\bigutimes
 \scriptstyle\biguplus\bigutimes$

$\displaystyle\biguplus_{i=1}^n\bigutimes_{i=1}^n$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think the `\times` in the example between b and c is just a little too low.  otherwise good.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Better now?

Comment: yes, quite acceptable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't think to a meaning for this symbol, though.

Answer (score 7):

The regular `\cup` is too narrow in order to allow the `\times` character inside it, so I chose `\bigcup` as an alternative. With the correct kerning, the symbol allows for usage in `\scriptstyle` etc. as well.

Since it is supposed to be an operator, `\DeclareMathOperator` seems to be a correct choice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\utimes}{\bigcup\utimeskern\times}
\newcommand{\utimeskern}{%
  \mkern-17.5mu
  \mathchoice{}{}{\mkern0.2mu}{\mkern0.5mu}%
}

\begin{document}

See $\utimes A$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are all excellent users of LaTeX. Upvote all.

Answer (score 7):

Based on my answer at [Combine two symbols to one fully scalable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243478/combine-two-symbols-to-one-fully-scalable), I provide `\cuptimes` and `\bigcuptimes`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\bigcuptimes}{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{.25\LMex}{\times}{\SavedStyle\bigcup}}}}}
\newcommand{\cuptimes}{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.3\LMpt}{c}{0\LMpt}{\SavedStyle^\times}{\SavedStyle\cup}}}}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}    
$\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$S_1\cup S_2$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\displaystyle\bigcuptimes_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$\bigcuptimes_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$S_1\cuptimes S_2$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\scriptstyle\bigcuptimes_{i\in I}S_i$\hspace{40pt}
$\scriptscriptstyle\bigcuptimes_{i\in I}S_i$
    \vspace{20pt}

$\scriptstyle S_1\cuptimes S_2$\hspace{40pt}
$\scriptscriptstyle S_1\cuptimes S_2$
\end{document}
```

[image]