# Place a given symbol inside \cup like \uplus

Tags: math-mode, macros, superscripts

does any know how I can create a command that places a symbol given as an argument inside \cup?

For instance, the command \uplus has the symbol '+' inside \cup. 
I would like to be able to place any given symbol inside \cup (in special, the letter 'k').
An important issue is that the size of the symbol must respect the superscript math mode. Actually, the size of this symbol has to be a bit smaller, so as is '+' inside \cup in \uplus.

The figure below explains better what I am talking about.

[image]

I would like to obtain something similar to the second (from left to right) case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243478/combine-two-symbols-to-one-fully-scalable

Comment: I don't think so. My question is a little different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\stackinset` command from `stackengine` can do that:

```
\documentclass[border = 2pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{stackengine} %
\newcommand\cupk{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{0.2ex}{\scriptscriptstyle k}{\scriptstyle\cup}}}

\begin{document}

$B^{\cupk} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only possible suggestion would be to change `\stackMath` declaration to `\ensurestackMath{...}`, so that current text/math stack setting is not perturbed by the macro.

Comment: I confess I had forgotten this command. I'll fix  the code at once. Thanks!

Comment: `\ensurestackMath` takes an argument, so you need to enclose everything that follows in braces...[at least that is the official syntax].

Comment: Of course. I guess I was out of my mind…

Answer (score 9):

We need fully scalable fonts for this, so `fix-cm` if the document is in the standard Computer Modern font. It is not necessary if other fonts are chosen.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vcup}[1]{%
  \mathbin{\vphantom{\cup}\mathpalette\vcup@{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\vcup@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\cup$\cr
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{%
      \dimexpr\depth+\demote@{#1}\dimexpr1.5pt\relax\relax
    }{\fontsize{\demote@{#1}\dimexpr\f@size pt}{\z@}\selectfont\check@mathfonts
      $\m@th#2$}%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\demote@}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.7
  \else\ifx#1\textstyle 0.7
  \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle 0.5
  \else 0.4\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\vcup{k}B^{\vcup{k}}$

$\uplus\scriptstyle\uplus\scriptscriptstyle\uplus$
$\vcup{k}\scriptstyle\vcup{k}\scriptscriptstyle\vcup{k}$
$\vcup{y}\scriptstyle\vcup{y}\scriptscriptstyle\vcup{y}$
$\vcup{g}\scriptstyle\vcup{g}\scriptscriptstyle\vcup{g}$

\end{document}
```

[image]