# Special union operation

Tags: math-mode, graphs, math-operators

I have defined a graph operation which is somehow related to the graph union operation. I want the operation to look like in the figure below. [image: figure]

I will use the operation several times so I would like to be able to put different characters inside the union symbol. I have tried to produce the result by manipulating the code given by the user named egreg  in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union) post but I was not successful. Any ideas on how could I produce such an operation?

Comment: What if the index is *j*? What should be in the middle of the union symbol?

Comment: @egreg The indices of the graphs on which the operation is performed may or may not depend on what is in the middle of the union symbol. What you see in the picture happens to be what I might need in one of the theorems. For example, at some point I will need something  where the operation is performed on two graphs which do not have index and the letter in the middle of the union operation is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer at [Combine two symbols to one fully scalable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243478/combine-two-symbols-to-one-fully-scalable/243480#243480), I provide `\cuplet[]` and `\bigcuplet[]`, where the optional argument (default `i`) is the embedded variable.  To get limits, I just append `\limits...` to the usage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\bigcuplet}[1][i]{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{+.3\LMex}{#1}{\SavedStyle\bigcup}}}}}
\newcommand{\cuplet}[1][i]{\mathop{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.3\LMpt}{c}{0\LMpt}{\SavedStyle^{#1}}{\SavedStyle\cup}}}}}
\begin{document}

\[
G_i \bigcuplet\limits_{i=1}^n G_{i+1}\hspace{20pt}
\scriptstyle G_j \bigcuplet[j]\limits_{j=1}^n G_{j+1}\hspace{20pt}
\scriptscriptstyle G_k \bigcuplet[k]\limits_{k=1}^n G_{k+1}
\]

\[
G_i \cuplet\limits_{i=1}^n G_{i+1}\hspace{20pt}
\scriptstyle G_j \cuplet[j]\limits_{j=1}^n G_{j+1}\hspace{20pt}
\scriptscriptstyle G_k \cuplet[k]\limits_{k=1}^n G_{k+1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to define an operation where the symbol within the union symbol can be given at each use? For example, something like \cuplet[2] which means that the symbol within the union symbol will be two. As I said in the post, this operation will be used many times and I would not like to have to define a new operation each time I use it.

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj It does what you already suggested: `\cuplet[2]` puts a `2` inside the cup.  If you prefer making the argument *mandatory* (to be used with curly rather than square braces), just remove the `[i]` from the definitions optional specification.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked that before commenting. One last thing, is it possible to make the union symbol  at \cuplet a little bigger so that the letter inside it does not fit tightly?

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj It is not easy to make `\cuplet` bigger (other than going to `\bigcuplet`).  On could with some ease make the embedded letter smaller (via `\scalebox` for example).  Recall though, the middle and right side of my image are using `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, which is certainly not the norm you will be dealing with.  The left hand images are really the reference images.

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj Actually, you can scale the cup, as well.  Try this: `\newcommand{\cuplet}[1][i]{\mathop{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{.3\LMpt}{c}{0\LMpt}{\SavedStyle^{#1}}{\scaleobj{1.2}{\cup}}}}}}`

Comment: Thank you, it is perfect! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj That's OK.  Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj I vote for Steven instead of you :-)

Comment: As always, thank you @Sebastiano.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes aahahah...no thank you...please...because what I've always done comes from my heart and not from my head.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!

Comment: @KristinaDedndreaj Also you have received my upvoted :-)...here we are a great and solid group!!!

Comment: @Sebastiano It is great when those who have greater knowledge share it with us.